# Как вернуть массив строк разделенных 0x0A

Tags: php

Друзья, сразу прошу строго не судить, я только учусь.

Передомной стоит четкая задача:

1) Есть скрипт который посылает на мой сервер GET запрос. В ответ на этот запрос я должен вернуть ему массив строк в таком формате:

номер строки; имя пользователя; пароль;0x0A - это окончание каждой строки я так понимаю?

Вопрос что как это сделать? я пробовал так:

```
echo "1;D;".date("d.m.Y H:i:s")."\n";
echo "2;C;".$data_card['code'].";0; ;".mb_substr($data_card['owner'], 0, 16, "UTF-8").";0;01.12.2300\n";
echo "3;L;1;26.10.2016;30.10.2016;777;".$data_card['dt'].";5.00;26.10.2016 09:01:23\n";
echo "4;t;1\n";
echo "5;e;2\n";
echo "6;#";
```

но как я понял это я вывел чисто строки на экран а не вернул массив строк, так ведь? у меня задача вернуть массив строк что бы скрипт его обработал. как реализован скрипт и что внутри - не ясно, эта информация не доступна

Comment: ну, для начала нужно проанализировать, в каком виде и куда приходит GET. какие заголовки требует ответ? какой тип ответа (Content-Type: plain/text) ? т.е. нужно добавить вот все это перед выводом, а дальше - все правильно. вывод уйдет в ответ, а не на экран

Comment: Что бы быть точнее: Данные Get запросы посылает контроллер оборудования. именно поэтому мы не можем посмотреть как реализован сам скрипт, никакой документации нету. чисто сказали что посылается запрос такого плана: http://domain.com/index.php?r=terminals/Download&id=1111&cardver=204 - на такой гет запрос мы должны вернуть массив строк. данные в каждой строке должны быть разделены ";" Сама строка должна заканчиваться символом 0x0A - как я понимаю это \n?

Comment: и вот эти вот все эхи у тебя в index.php? ты пробовал в браузере посмотреть, что твой скрипт выводит на такой запрос?
и да, 0x0A - это \n, все правильно (в браузере игнорируется, поэтому у тебя в ответе будет все в одну строку), и к последней строке тоже \n прилепи